# How can I organize a project with exercises in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm doing self-study with a book. 
It has a lot of different small exercises.
I don't want to begin a new project everytime, so I want to keep them all in one place organized by chapters.

But I'm a complete beginner and having trouble even with that.
Here's a picture of a mistake that pops up and you can kind of get an idea of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

"1p5" and "1p7" stand for exercises 1.5 and 1.7.

If you have an idea on how to organize that sort of thing better, help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You should enclose that line of code in a method, for example a main method so you can run it... `public static void main(String[] args) { /*your code here */ }`. That should get rid of the warning.

Comment: Oh right, thanks. I just read somewhere that there can only be one main in a project. But I guess for the sake of exercises it's fine.

Comment: There can be only one main per class - and when you run a project with several class having a main method, you need to choose one of them. But nothing prevents you from having as many main entry points as you want in a given project.

Comment: Oooooh now I got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem from the image is that you forgot to add your call to `System.out` inside a method such as `main`:

```
class NewClass1p7 {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("...");
    }
}
```

Your package organization seems fine and not related to the problem.